# Separating comma delimeted values from a variable

Tags: sql-server

I need the script as shown in the expected output but whatever i do, whatever i use, i end up with script shown in current output.

```
DECLARE @query varchar(max),
@col  varchar(250) = 'd1,d2,d3'


Set @query = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[MYTABLE](
                   '+@col+'
                   )
                   SELECT  ''~N'' AS ['+@col+']'
print @query
```

current output

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MYTABLE](
                   d1,d2,d3
                   )
                   SELECT  '~N' AS [d1,d2,d3]
```

Expected output

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MYTABLE](
                   d1,d2,d3
                   )
                   SELECT  '~N' AS [d1],
                           '~N' AS [d2],
                           '~N' AS [d3]
```

Comment: Your table definition and insert defintion doesn't match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work for any data split by comma and do what You wanted.

```
DECLARE @query varchar(max),
    @col  varchar(250) = 'd1,d2,d3', @word varchar(250) =''


    Set @query = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[MYTABLE](
                '+@col+'
                )'
    while CHARINDEX( ',', @col)> 1
    BEGIN
    set @word = SUBSTRING(@col, 0,CHARINDEX(',', @col))
    set @col = SUBSTRING(@col,CHARINDEX( ',', @col)+1, LEN(@col))
    set @query = @query +


                ' SELECT  ''~N'' AS ['+@word+']'
    END
    set @query = @query +


                ' SELECT  ''~N'' AS ['+@col+']'

    print @query
```

Answer (score 1):

Your table output is wrong and this type of solutions doesn't scale,try simplfying your schema to avoid this..

At a high level,this can be achieved by
1.splitting comma seperated values which will return a column list
2.Then Convert column to rows..

**Demo:**

I used one of the split string [functions from here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)..

```
--create table #temp
--(
--d1 varchar,
--d2 varchar,
--d3 varchar
--)


declare @q varchar(10)
set @q='d1,d2,d3'

;with cte
as
(select * from
[dbo].[SplitStrings_Numbers](@q,',')
)
insert into #temp
select 
max(case when item='d1' then item end)  as d1,
max(case when item='d2' then item end)  as d2,
max(case when item='d3' then item end)  as d3
from cte
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    DECLARE @query varchar(max),
`@col  varchar(250) = 'd1,d2,d3',`
`@col1  varchar(250) = ''`

`Set @query = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[MYTABLE](`
                `   '+@col+'`
              `     )'    `          


`SELECT @col=COALESCE(@col+',','')`
` WHILE(CHARINDEX(',',@col) > 0)`
<br/>
 `BEGIN`


`SET @col1= left(@col, charindex(',', @col+',')-1)`
<br/>
`set  @query=@query+'SELECT  ''~N'' AS ['+@col1+'],'`
<br/>
`IF(CHARINDEX(',',@col) > 0 )`
<br/>
`BEGIN`
<br/>
    `SET @col = STUFF(@col, 1, CHARINDEX(',', @col+''), '') `
<br/>       
`END`
<br/>
`ELSE`<br/>
`IF(LEN(@col)>0)`<br/>
`BEGIN`<br/>
    `SET @col = STUFF(@col, 1,LEN(@col) , '')   `   <br/>

`END`<br/>
`END`<br/>
`SET @query = STUFF(@query, len(@query), 1, '') `<br/>  
`print @query`
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer

```
Declare @SQLString varchar(max)
Declare @SQLString2 varchar(max)
DECLARE @col_by_dim varchar(8000) = 'd1,d2,d3,d4',
@dim_name1 varchar(250) = 'CarrierEnrollment'
Set @SQLString = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[zzz_'+@dim_name1+'](
                   '+@col_by_dim+'
                   )
Select '


DECLARE @pos INT
DECLARE @len INT
DECLARE @value varchar(8000)

set @pos = 0
set @len = 0

WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @col_by_dim, @pos+1)>0
BEGIN
    set @len = CHARINDEX(',', @col_by_dim, @pos+1) - @pos
    set @value = SUBSTRING(@col_by_dim, @pos, @len)

    set @SQLString2 = '
    ''~N'' AS ['+@value+'],'

    set @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @col_by_dim, @pos+@len) +1
    Set @SQLString = @SQLString + @SQLString2 
END
print @SQLString + ' 
    ''~N'' AS '+ '['+SUBSTRING(@col_by_dim, @pos, @len)+']'
```

Comment: thank you all, i figured it out. thanks for everyones help

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @query varchar(max),
@col  varchar(250) = 'd1,d2,d3',@value varchar(max)


set @query='INSERT INTO [dbo].[MYTABLE](
                   '+@col+'
                   )
                   SELECT   '

declare c cursor for
select val from Split(@col, ',')
open c
fetch next from c into @value
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin

Set @query = @query+ '''~N'''+' AS ['+@value+']'+','+CHAR(13)+char(9)+char(9)+char(9)+char(9)+char(9)+char(9)+char(9)
fetch next from c into @value
end
close c
deallocate c


set @query= substring(@query,1,len(@query))
print @query
```